# What is current directory name?

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to see the current directory. Below is the current directory. How to know the directory name? Thank you

**kueve@ubuntu:~$**

Is this root or home directory?

Comment: `~` is the home directory for your user account. `/root` is the root directory. When in doubt, the `pwd` command will let you know your current directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. yes its. one more question, why we need to type "/" before some directory such as /root or /etc while other do not need?

Comment: When you prefix a directory with `/` you are stating a full path. So `cd /var/log` will bring you to that specific directory. When you state just the directory name, you are using a *relative* path to your current location. So if you are in `~` and enter `cd other`, you will change to `/home/{USER}/other` if it exists.

Comment: Thank you so much, very good explanation!

Comment: @matigo Let me know if you feel otherwise, but isn't `/` the "root" directory, and `/root` the *home* directory for the *root user*?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
pwd
```

will show you the full absolute pathname of the current directory.

The symbol `~` is a shortcut for current user's home directory, so if you see `~` in the prompt (as in your question), your current directory is the home directory. This is regardless if your current user is root or non-root. If you switch from `kueve` user to root (for example by typing `sudo -i`), your prompt will show

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

and `~` here will mean **root user's home directory** (typically `/root`), while in the prompt

```
kueve@ubuntu:~$
```

`~` means `kueve` user's home directory (typically `/home/kueve`).

If you want to know, what exactly `~` means, type the command

```
echo ~
```

It will show you the full absolute pathname of the `~` directory, ie. home directory.

BTW. Do not confuse **root user's home directory** (`/root`) with **root directory** (`/`) - the latter is the top directory of the entire filesystem tree. In some old *nix systems (not Linux), the root directory was also actually the root user's home directory (there was no `/root` directory by default - of course you could always create one manually and change the root user's home directory to it), but it isn't so anymore since long time.